# Link com resultado do ajax nao aceita click

Tags: php, html, jquery

Tenho o seguinte condigo com chamada ajax:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".atualizarAjax").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "<?= HOME ?>/ajax_carrinho.php",
            data :  "id="+id,
            beforeSend: function(){
            $(".carregando").show();
            $(".carregando").html("<img src='<?= HOME ?>/img/ajax-loader.gif' style='width: 20px; height: 20px;'> Adicionando...");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('.carrinhoGO').html(data);
                $('.recarrega').load("<?= HOME ?>/ajax_produtos.php?id="+id);
                $(".carregando").hide();
                
            }
        });
   return false;       
    });
});
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<a href="#" id="atualizarAjax" data-id="<?= $value['id']?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs atualizarAjax"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Comprar</a>
```

O problema e que no arquivo que carrega nesta linha:

```js
 $('.recarrega').load("<?= HOME ?>/ajax_produtos.php?id="+id);
```

Contem um link a ser clicado:

```
<a href="#" id="atualizarAjax" data-id="<?= $value['id']?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs atualizarAjax"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Comprar</a>
```

Este link não funciona, pois deveria chamar o ajax novamente e não chama.
Alguem pode dar uma força?

Answer (score 0):

Como o `href` do link possui apenas uma *hash* (`#`), você está querendo capturar o click no link através de um `.click` ou `.on("click")`. Como esse link foi adicionado de forma dinâmica na página pelo Ajax, ele não constava no DOM quando a página foi renderizada.

O que você tem que fazer é pegar o clique pelo `document` e não diretamente pelo elemento (por que ele não existe no DOM) usando o método `.on`, desta forma:

```
$(document).on("click", "#atualizarAjax", function(){

   // ação quando o link for clicado

});
```